# How to implement my android algorithm on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an android app working this way:

1. User read QR-code with my specific URL
2. If the app installed it intercepts this URL and handles it somehow.
3. If app not installed standard browser opens this URL and it leads to Google play on app page.
4. When user install and run app first time it read browser's history and look for my URL.
5. If app found URL in browser's history then it handles this URL again.

Is it possible to implement this behavior on iPhone/iPad?
I suppose key features here are to read browser history and to intercept http URL's.

If this is impossible how would you implement this thing on iOS?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In ios your app will not be able to read the browser's history. And you can forget your java code, objective-c is somewhat different, the frameworks you'll be using are totally different.

Comment: I believe you are totally right. What I'm asking about is a way to implement this functionality on iOS. It can be any other approach. It's open question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom application URLs in the form: myApp://...  iOS will automatically launch the application if present.  The logic for handling the 'not-installed' case <strike>has to be in the QR code scanning app.</strike> can be handled by the scanned website via a forwarding link using the iOS custom URL scheme (this might be useful for usage stats).

[Additional info on implementing Custom URLs...](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: If I change URL I'll get two problems
1. I have too change android app
2. Browser doesn't understand this URL, so item 3 cannot be implemented
I want keep URL the same!